# Android - AppCompat spinner not showing correctly

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-appcompat

Using `AppCompat v7 22.1.1`

I have a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation containing simple basic Spinner views. This is the result :

[image: Screenshot]

The bottom line is missing and there doesn't seem to be any margin between spinners. Isn't this how a Material Spinner would look like ?

[image]

Comment: well what does your xml look like, what do you mean by "bottom line"?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just a Spinner with a width set to match_parent and height to wrap_content, inside a LinearLayout

Comment: and what do you mean by "bottom line"

Comment: that is the holo style, the material style does not have the line at the bottom. what you see is what the material style looks like

Comment: Im not sure, but have you set the `colorAccent` attribute?

Comment: I think you should, i wlll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed the Holo Theme.

Answer (score 0):

In your values/styles.xml,

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

In values-v21/styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```